# How long does it take to start a Spark job on a running EMR cluster?

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-emr

Some unknowns that I currently have

1. What steps happen between running `spark-submit` and the job executing business logic (after all initialization is done)?
2. What factors can increase/decrease initialization duration?
3. Any EMR-specific factors?

I'm asking because I'd like to find out if it's realistic to have a job start running business logic within seconds after submission.

**Note**: We can assume that there are no other jobs running on the cluster.

Answer (score 0):

Considering all initialization is done I'll consider you're talking about EMR set up. Not many if we consider that they are no other job.

Within second it's possible but it's not granted. Do your job needs dependencies ? If yes, it will be a bit longer on how many you specify.
Also where is stored your main script/jar. Usually you submit a job through AWS EMR SDK and not directly though spark-submit (even if in the end it's the same). Within a minute it shouldn't be a problem for small jobs

For the second question, initialization duration I'll consider you're talking about the EMR boot up. Will depend if you have bootstrap actions or not set up. If not, it'll last a 10 mins aprox if AWS can easily find resources (EC2 instances)